# how to call addEventListener on scroll in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the background color of body on scroll, but it seems like the scroll event listener isn't working. here is my code:

```
"use strict";

// Get all the sections with the class "section"
const sections = document.querySelectorAll(".section");

// Function to update the background color based on the section in view
const updateBackgroundColor = () => {
  console.log("updateBackgroundColor called");

  const scrollPosition = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;
  console.log("scrollPosition:", scrollPosition);

  sections.forEach((section) => {
    const sectionTop = section.getBoundingClientRect().top + scrollPosition;
    const sectionBottom = sectionTop + section.offsetHeight;
    const backgroundColor = section.getAttribute("data-bg-color");

    console.log(
      `Section: ${section.classList}, Top: ${sectionTop}, Bottom: ${sectionBottom}, Background Color: ${backgroundColor}`
    );

    if (scrollPosition >= sectionTop && scrollPosition <= sectionBottom) {
      // The section is in view
      if (backgroundColor) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
      }
    }
  });
};

// Get the container element
const scroller = document.querySelector(".scroller");

// Add an event listener for the "wheel" event on the container
scroller.addEventListener("wheel", (event) => {
  // Prevent the default scroll behavior
  event.preventDefault();

  // Calculate the scroll direction
  const delta = event.deltaY;

  // Scroll to the next or previous section based on scroll direction
  if (delta > 0) {
    scroller.scrollBy({
      top: window.innerHeight,
      behavior: "smooth",
    });
  } else if (delta < 0) {
    scroller.scrollBy({
      top: -window.innerHeight,
      behavior: "smooth",
    });
  }
});

window.addEventListener("scroll", updateBackgroundColor);
```

I am getting nothing on the console

I am trying to change the background color whenever the user scrolls.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I recommend checking out [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: Show us your HTML code. I have a feeling that you've wrapped your sections inside your "scroller" element, which has "preventDefault". If I'm right, your scroll event is being canceled. I quickly made a mockup fiddle of your code myself and had the same issue. Once the preventDefault was removed, the issue was solved: https://jsfiddle.net/5ozwh7e3/

Comment: https://codepen.io/atomiks/pen/dgMNwG

Comment: https://codepen.io/bugaimhs-the-decoder/pen/OJrjrmE
@icecub here is the full code, i have made some changes in js and its working kinda

Answer (score 0):

The [`wheel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event) event is not synonymous with the `scroll` event.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event):

> Note: Don't confuse the wheel event with the scroll event. The default
> action of a wheel event is implementation-specific, and doesn't
> necessarily dispatch a scroll event. Even when it does, the delta*
> values in the wheel event don't necessarily reflect the content's
> scrolling direction. Therefore, do not rely on the wheel event's
> delta* properties to get the scrolling direction. Instead, detect
> value changes of scrollLeft and scrollTop of the target in the scroll
> event.

use the [`scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll_event) event and make sure the document is tall enough and with enough content for scrolling to be able to take place.

```js
addEventListener("scroll", function(event){
  console.log("scrolling");
});
```

```html
<p>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

problem is not in EventListener. I think it's in your function! Can I see your console after scrolling and your HTML code, please.

Comment: This is not an answer and should be a comment. Work on providing [good, quality answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to get your reputation high enough to be able to comment.

Comment: How I shoud answer if I have not enough information, I also don't have enough reputation to comment on it or do anything else.

Comment: If you have a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), go ahead and post it as an answer. After doing this for a short while, you'll gain enough reputation points to be able to comment. Until then, if you don't have a good answer, you'll be better off not adding anything. Following these guidelines helps to keep Stack Overflow consistent and valuable for users. We don't want to see answers that are nothing more than questions back to the OP or answers that try to engage the OP in a conversation.